# How to use PostCSS in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor, postcss

I want to use PostCSS in my Meteor App but I can't found any package to do this, so does anybody know how to integrate PostCSS in Meteor JS?

Answer (score 1):

I just leave it here. This is a PostCSS package for Meteor, maybe someone will be interested in helping with this: https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/postcss

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with 1.4. This project is abandoned.

Comment: Yes, you can say so, but this is not because I don't care. This is because Meteor's build system is very complicated and not elastic, and maintaining PostCSS support is almost impossible. Sorry for that, but I rather go with Webpack where PostCSS integration is stupid simple. Of course you can't use Webpack with Meteor, but you could do something like: http://julian.io/react-with-webpack-meteor-as-a-backend/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but I've been looking for an option on this and have found the following that may be of use to you:

https://github.com/stolinski/meteor-stylus-multi

Hope that helps you get going!